# Send an SMS from an Android 8.0 using adb

Tags: adb, sms, 8.0-oreo

A lot of docs are explaining how to send an SMS from an Android using adb command line, but none of these work for the newer Android version 8.

I am eager to know where are the docs for

```
service call isms [args...]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I finally can send SMS through the command line on an Android 8.0-oreo performing next steps:

- Installing the ShellMS app on the phone (once for ever)
- Going on the phone to Settings > Apps > ShellMS > Permissions > Enable all the permissions (once for ever). This step will no longer be necessary once an issue about permissions will be fixed
- Connecting the phone to the computer with USB (and giving permission on the phone for accessing data, if asked)
- Issuing next script on the computer:

```
#!/bin/bash
phonenumber="$1"
message="$2"
# escape double quotes
message=${message//\"/\\\"} 
adb shell "am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS -e contact \"$phonenumber\" -e msg \"$message\""
```